# How to copy Pentaho Kettle Job

Tags: pentaho, kettle

How can I copy an already existing Pentaho Kettle Job with its settings ?
I did selected all and `copy selected entries to clipboard` but it didn't copy the settings of the transformations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: I copied the whole `.kjb` file and renamed it